# Show that, given a query point q, it can be tested in time O(log n) whether q lies inside P

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, graph-algorithm

I am trying to solve some exercises of the book "Computational Geometry Algorithm and Applications, 3rd - de berg et al" of chapter 6 - Point Location. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve the following exercise:

```
Given a convex polygon P as an array of its n vertices in sorted order
along the boundary. Show that, given a query point q, it can be tested in
time O(log n) whether q lies inside P.
```

**My Idea so far:**
The only way I know to determine if a point lies inside p in O(log n) is to use a directed acyclic graph. In order to use a directed acyclic graph I need to build it, which is impossible in O(log n). So, somehow I need to use the ordered array, but the only solution I know with an array will cost O(N).

I hope that someone could help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea is basically to do a binary search, to find which 'segment' the point belongs to. The assumption here is that the polygon wraps around some fixed origin `O`, which is necessary to define an angular sorting routine.

[image]

To find whether `q` lies on the 'left' or 'right' of `P[n/2]` (by which I mean an anticlockwise or clockwise rotational difference about `O`), we do the 2D *cross-product*:

[image]

This is a real scalar. If this is positive, then `a` is to the right of `b`, and vice versa. In our code `a = q - O` and `b = P[i] - O`, where `i` is the index of the point on the polygon we are testing `q` against.

We can then use this test to find which 'segment' or 'wedge' `q` is in, i.e. which points of the polygon `q` is between (on the diagram these are `P[n/2 - 1]` and `P[n/2]`), using a binary search, which is O(log n). (I'll assume you know how to do this)

Once we know that, we need to know whether `q` is inside the 'wedge'.

[image]

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection, for two lines defined by pairs of points [(x1, y1), (x2, y2)] and [(x3, y3), (x4, y4)] respectively, their intersection point (Px, Py) is given by

[image]

Compute the intersection between [`Pl`, `Pr`] and [`q`, `O`] to give `s`, and compute the distance `|s - O|`. If this is greater than `|q - O|` then `q` is inside the polygon P, and vice versa.

(This step is of course O(1). There may however be more elegant ways of doing it - I'm just illustrating the logic behind it)

The total complexity is then O(log n) + O(1) = *O(log n)*.

Comment: Beautiful. I've never seen this technique before!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! May I ask what program you use to create these pictures?

Comment: @maffh no problem. now... this is embarrassing - most people use properly designated software like GIMP or Adobe Illustrator. I used PowerPoint  (~_~)  #SoftwareSacrilege

Comment: @user3235832 Great idea! Can I please use your images with reference?