# How to equally divide a polygon from its centroid and find the intersection coordinates in Python

Tags: python-3.x, geometry, coordinates

I have a polygon composed of multiple points (>30). I want to emanate rays from its centroid and divide the area equally (e.g. for every 5 degree). Then, I want to calculate the coordinates of the intersection points (interpolated by the original points composing the polygon) in Python
(please see the attached figure). I have already calculated the centroid.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGKcy.png]

Has anyone worked on the similar projects? Could anyone give me some hints and help on this?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are not here to ask the trivial question, "*how do I implement linear interpolation?*". Are you looking to fit some kind of curve to this, e.g. Bezier, so that the result is smooth?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I probably did not make myself clear.  I want to 1) have 72 rays originating from the centroid, and equally divide the area; 2) calculate the coordinates of point of intersections between the line segment and the rays. please see the modified picture. Thanks!

Comment: You haven't answered my question - how do you intend to interpolate between the points, linearly or by a curve (and if the latter, what type). The picture does not look like linear interpolation, so you have to specify.

Comment: Linear is fine. Bezier is too complicated for me. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, the method used on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135978/show-that-given-a-query-point-q-it-can-be-tested-in-time-olog-n-whether-q-li) may help you.

Comment: Note - equally-spaced angles don't divide general figure into pieces of equal area.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have vertex list/array `V` in CW or CCW order. And you did not mention specific value of starting angle (like 0)

Get the most right vertex of polygon - its index is `k`. Get its absolute angle relative to center as

```
an0 = atan2(V[k].y - center.y, V[k].x - center.x)
```

Get next angle as

```
an = an0 + delta
```

Seach for the edge that intersect ray with this angle - just check end angle in order

```
while anK < an  
    k = k + 1  //// check the end of edg
    anK = atan2(vertex[k].y - center.y, vertex[k].x - center.x)
    if anK < 0
         ank = anK + 2 * Pi   ////consider transition Pi => -Pi
```

Calculate intersection of angle `an` ray with line segment `V[k-1]..V[k]` solving equation for unknown t

```
V[k-1].y + t * (V[k].y - V[k-1].y) = tan(an) * (V[k-1].x + t * (V[k].x - V[k-1].x))
```

and get point

```
intersection.x = V[k-1].x + t * (V[k].x - V[k-1].x)
intersection.y = V[k-1].y + t * (V[k].y - V[k-1].y)
```

Repeat for next rays

P.S. It is possible to make calculations without extensive using of trigonometric functions - just starting calculation of some values like `cos(delta), sin(delta)`, but I doubt that you need such optimization at current step.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! it's very useful. I voted, but my reputation is low. Thanks again!